# Used memory into Yarn container

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

Is it possible to see how much memory is using inside of the yarn container? For example in configuration we we have:
Minimum Container Size (Memory) - 7168Mb
Maximum Container Size (Memory) - 186368Mb
And we run the job.
I would like to know how much memory in container the job is use?